# How access .htaccess file in windows server?

Tags: asp.net, helicontech

I am try to implement URL re-write functionality using Helicon Manager for
my ASP.net application running on windows server. I also generate a
.htaccess file and place in a root directory, but badly my application
failed to access this file and not performing the URL re-write. Here I want
to know how can i access .htaccess file through which we can perform a
successful URL re-write implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running on Apache Server or IIS? AFAIK IIS doesn't understand .htaccess (this knowledge dates back to 2005, I might be wrong), you might need to use a 3rd party component.

Comment: Application work on IIS server. Can u plz named such 3rd party tool?

Comment: @krisgupta5- look here http://forums.asp.net/p/1002727/1330189.aspx
I suggest searching for it abit since the link I suggested again dates back to 2005

Comment: @krisgupta5 - you can look for more solutions here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317175/what-replaces-htaccess-on-iis-asp-net-sites