# ASP.NET: Without using Membership API, how do you restrict resource files(e.g. jpg) to certain roles?

Tags: asp.net

It is easy to restrict access to aspx pages, just use role-checking logic in the code-behind. But resource files like a photo does not have a code behind to put role-checking logic, so how to restrict access?

Comment: I think this post should answer your question:
[What replaces .htaccess on IIS/ASP.NET sites?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317175/what-replaces-htaccess-on-iis-asp-net-sites

Comment: @The Jonas Persson: I have checked the thread you posted. It seems you could put the role-checking logic in a custom HttpModule's BeginRequest event?

Comment: I guess you could put it on a HttpModule, but the example in the accepted answer is using the `location` element in `web.config`. See here for more information [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx)

Comment: @TheJonasPersson the problem with using just location is that since items such as jpg and txt are not asp.net items forms authentication and membership classes mean nothing. as long as individual knows the direct path to the jpg or txt they can access those items without authentication or authorization. httphandlers have to be used for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to set up IIS. If you have IIS7+, it's a snap. Change your app pool from Classic to Integrated Pipeline. This allows managed modules and handlers to be applied to your static resource files. If you are using IIS6, [see this article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/784eeb32-d781-4917-95b3-34f302a81680.mspx?mfr=true).

Second, you may need to ensure this setting in your web.config (for IIS7):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Things like FormsAuth should now work the same as they would for ASPX, etc., meaning you can restrict paths to authorized users only by using web.config (for example).

**Update**

In response to Aperture's comment below:

Outside of using `RoleProviders`, ASP.NET can figure out the roles for a principal either by reading groups a user belongs to when using Windows auth, or manually changing the roles by replacing the current IPrincipal in your application, preferably during `AuthenticateRequest`.

`Global.asax.cs`

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = sender as HttpApplication;
    var context = application.Context;

    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return; // if the user hasn't been authenticated by another module such as FormsAuth, don't do anything further

    string[] roleNames = FindRolesForUser(context.User.Identity.Name); // this method you will create to figure out what roles the specified user has
    context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(context.User.Identity.Name), roleNames); // updates the current principal. 
}
```

Now, as far as checking the roles we've specified above, there are a number of ways. You could create a custom HttpModule that looks for paths that end in JPG, GIF, JS, etc. and then simply check `context.User.IsInRole`. You could also simply use `location` and `authorization` in your web.config:

```
   <location path="images">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/> <!-- or perhaps <allow roles="Admins" /> it's up to you -->
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

The bottom line is, **you can't execute any managed code during the request to static resources until you either configure Integrated Pipeline, or map static resources to the ASP.NET ISAPI module**. So, my answer is appropriate.

Comment: By logical deduction, if you do not enable Membership API, IIS would have no way to know what a "role" is and who is in what role, and all authorization modules still require the concept of roles, so this approach does not work. The manual role-checking logic would have to be put somewhere in the flow of control when the page request comes in.

Comment: You are assuming that roles for a principal can only be set by Role or Membership providers, and that is incorrect. You can set roles manually in your application for the current principal (say, in Global.asax during the AuthenticateRequest event). The point is, however, that your question insinuated you've already figured out how to set the roles to each request, and you just need to figure out how to get role checking to be applied to non-ASPX resources.

Comment: Hi, I'd like ask you a question that have been boethering me: As I have no commercial experience, do commercial web developers more likely than not use the Membership API or skip it for their own code? Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET is designed to utilize Membership and Role providers, so in leveraging them you can save yourself some time. You do have the option of writing your own implementation of a provider, to connect to your own database or change some default behavior you don't agree with. It's quite extensible. All I can say is that lots of developers DO use them, for all manners of projects of varying sizes.